# When attempting run a python script from within another python script, I get 'permission denied'!

Tags: python, python-2.7, download, sh, permission-denied

So, I was writing a python script, and it automatically downloads an update at the beginning of the script. Ok, so? So when I try to overwrite it, it gives me `sh: /Users/<user>/Desktop/<scriptname>.py: Permission denied` using CodeRunner 2.0.2, IDLE 2.7.9, and PythonLauncher. Here's the affected snippit:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd = (str(cwd) + "/<scriptname>.py")
update = urllib.URLopener()
cwd = str(cwd)
print "Downloading Update..."
update.retrieve("http://<site_domain>/<scriptname>.py",cwd)
time.sleep(1.25)
print "Update Dowloaded! Please Wait..."
time.sleep(2.5)
os.system(cwd)
```

I found this odd since people say that it should overwrite no problemo, however, I found it odd when there was no brother `.pyc`, meaning it may have been attempting to read and write at the same time, not to mention it worked fine, then suddenly went kaput.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`os.system(cmd)` will call `[current directory]/<scriptname>/py`.

Instead of calling the script outright (it may not be executable), pass it to Python:

```
cwd = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "<scriptname>.py")
...
os.system('{} {}'.format('python', cmd))
```